# General unit testing concepts/practices in JavaScript against different browsers?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, cross-browser

I’ve been writing unit tests in strongly typed languages and I have a fair good understanding about it. When writing unit tests in JavaScript to verify if certain functions are working properly in certain browsers I am back to the manual testing. I have no understanding of how it works. **Because JavaScript is meant to close the gap between data and presentation and make it more interactive. And everything is happening within browsers and it's more to do with UI.** So I am assuming that if I were going to write a unit test I would write something like (in pseudo code):

```
run function A
check DOM if certain element has been created
  if not then fail
check if element is visible
  if not then fail
check for the content of that element
  if null then fail
etc…
```

Writing these tests seem like “hard coding” to me and what’s missing is that the tests wouldn’t be able to tell if it’s been rendered properly, it's only doing the pure functional tests. So I am wondering if someone can explain to me what are the proper test procedures in JavaScript, how to do build automations and some general concepts in doing it. I was just looking at [John Resig's project testswarm](http://testswarm.com/) but yet to figure out what it’s about. I am also reading about [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) at the moment.

I am looking for some introductory materials on the concepts/practices that can me started. I am not looking for specific libraries or tools unless they have good introduction on the concepts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely a confusing and dynamic area of web development right now. In my mind, there are a few important feature distinctions of JS testing:

- pure unit tests, that test plain Javascript code. You can assert that `a+b=3`, or whatever. We've had only a few problem that fit into this category. When discussion options, there are lots of alternatives to the JSUnit (a JUnit port). They break down into TDD vs. BDD and naming choices within those categories.
- Javascript + DOM tests. So much of the code written these days is about manipulating the DOM. eg. `assertEqual('<a><div /></a>', $('div').wrap('a'));`  For DOM-based JS testing, you either need to move to in-browser testing, or use a library like env.js.
- There are also mocking & stubbing (smoke), async and other helpers

There are two places tests can run:

- out-of-browser testing (generally faster to run, so they can be used in a TDD enviroment)
- in-browser testing (slower, more complicated, but provide more accurate cross-browser test results)

Selenium runs in-browser, so it is great for integration tests. If you have nothing else working, this is a good starting point. It's been around for a few years and supports most popular browsers and languages. Watching [a screencast like this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/116-selenium) might be helpful. And [this documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html) might give you a flavor of what the tests would look like.  There are also quite a few other tutorials and screencasts around, but many of them get bogged down in the technical doodoo you don't care about, so you have to be selective.

Finally, here's an example from [blue ridge](http://blog.thinkrelevance.com/2009/5/12/blue-ridge-1-0-javascript-unit-testing-for-rails-scandalous), which is a collection of tools pulled together for out-of-browser testing (and manual in-browser test) for Rails:

```
Screw.Unit(function() {
    describe("Your application javascript", function() {
        it("accesses the DOM from fixtures/application.html", function() {
            expect($$('.select_me').length).to(equal, 2);
        });
    });
});
```

This is a single test using an rspec-like syntax test test that a couple elements are there. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Check jsTestDriver. I think this is one of the best:

> The goal of JsTestDriver is to build a
>   JavaScript test runner which:
>
> easily integrates with continuous
>   builds systems and allows running
>   tests on multiple browsers quickly to
>   ease TDD style development.

http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the presenter pattern for your JavaScript and just using simple unit tests. The Google Testing Blog has some decent resources.

I'd start here:

http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2009/02/with-all-sport-drug-scandals-of-late.html

I've done this in Flex (ActionScript) projects for all my UI code and found it has been working very well. You want to isolate your functionality so you avoid testing things that have already been tested extensively by the browser vendors.

Comment: Also check this link I found in the comments of the linked post:
http://www.atomicobject.com/pages/Presenter+First

Answer (score 0):

I hear about [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) sometimes. I've never used it but maybe it could help you.

> Selenium Remote Control (RC) runs your
>   tests in multiple browsers and
>   platforms. Tweak your tests in your
>   preferred language.

I also found a blog article: [Unit Testing in JavaScript](http://www.notesfromatooluser.com/2008/11/unit-testing-in-javascript.html), which mentions so:[Looking for a better JavaScript unit test tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-unit-test-tool-for-javascript).

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking for any specific frameworks what I am looking for is to understand the concepts in doing unit test in javascript, specifically against different browsers.

Comment: You'll never find out what suits your needs until you try a couple of different tools. From what I understand, from those people that test, everyone has their way to test, depending on how JS fits into the overall solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Test Swarm](http://testswarm.com/)

Comment: That's currently still in alpha and is only open to open source projects, it looks like.