# Javascript unit testing in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, unit-testing

I am doing a firefox extension using eclipse and need to know how I can do unit testing for that project.

Comment: General question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [Jasmine Framework](http://jasmine.github.io/) for that.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using JSTestDriver, http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver, and it is an excellent framework. Lightning fast testing, test on save, and other cool features.

Initial setup is a bit complicated, but it's certainly worth it.

Comment: I love jsTestDriver too, but it really tests Javascript inside a web page. The original questioner is building an extension.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) in the past, but this project is no longer maintained.