# What's your favorite way to test the javascript in your djangoapp?

Tags: javascript, django, testing

I've been working with django a lot. Now I have an app with JavaScript integrated which I want to test. What's your favorite way to integrate real-browser-tests in the django unittest environment? twill? selenium? windmill?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already, you should be using `nose` for your basic unit-testing needs, along with the `django-nose` app.

Having done that, when you're ready to automate your actual browser testing you should grab `alfajor`, which is a very handy python wrapper around various libraries like selenium and windmill. Developers are actively working on integrating it as a django app in `django_alfajor`.

In terms of pure javascript unit tests though, there's a decent write-up [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool) on the different frameworks.

Comment: After installing django-nose and django-nose-selenium, I've tried to make a very simple test with selenium. It seems there's a bug with my combination of browser/selenium rc :-(

Answer (score 0):

A company I used to intern for Selenium for Javascript testing on server-side.

I think they use [**Django-Selenium**](http://code.google.com/p/django-selenium/).

Hope this helps...

Comment: the google code page of django-selenium  reads "activity: none". seems not to be maintained any longer.