# Tibco pagebus framework testing

Tags: publish-subscribe, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-rv, tibco-gi

We are using the Tibco pagebus framework as a middle ware for message publishing/subscribing.

Enterprise application we are developing is using the above framework.

Can you please suggest me how to test the Tibco pagebus framework.(framework testing)

Anyone having idea on this framework and how to test this framework.

Awaiting for the response.

thanks in advance

Regards,
Malju

Answer (score 2):

Yes, The Open Ajax Hub is a version of the TIBCO pagebus. TIBCO contributed the code to Open Ajax Alliance. It also comes with a full set of Unit tests based on JsUnit.

The main difference is that TIBCO uses "." as the subject separator so "europe.england.sport.football" would be a sub-set of "europe.england.sport" and so on.

Open Ajax hub I believe does not specify a separator, but allows the user to specify one. This is due to a disagreement by DojoToolkit who wanted to use "/" as the subject separator and not "."

Answer (score 0):

TIBCO Pagebus is a JavaScript framework providing messaging functionality with the Browser, so your best bet is to pick one of the JavaScript Unit testing tools. This topic is covered in another Stack Overflow question at [JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool)

The Dojo Objective Harness appears to be the preferred option, but a there are a whole heap listed.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/util/doh.html#id1

Comment: PageBus is an implementation of the [OpenAjax Hub 2.0 Spec](http://www.openajax.org/member/wiki/OpenAjax_Hub_2.0_Specification). The OpenAjax Alliance have their own [Open Source Implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openajaxallianc/files/OpenAjaxHub/). I don't know how similar of different it is to PageBus.