# Is there an AJAX web-based Junit TestRunner?

Tags: java, html, ajax, junit

What I'm looking for is a TestRunner implementation for running a suite of Java JUnit tests within a browser.  The intention is that non-developers can execute the tests by visiting a browser page.  Test results should be dynamically updated to the browser page with something like AJAX after each test and/or suite has completed.

I've seen a few attempts at this, but the ones I'm aware of execute all of the tests before showing any results to the browser.  Take [mistletoe](http://mistletoe.qos.ch/manual.html) for example.

Ideally, the implementation would be inspired by the JUnit testrunners found in IDEs such as [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).  Is anyone aware of such a TestRunner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, and I've just come across [ktrwjr](http://code.google.com/p/ktrwjr/), which I'm just about to use to integrate into my web app to run my JUnit integration tests.

Edit: I've just realised this is for testing apps developed on GAE/j. So close...

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this Question Might Help:
[JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool)

Comment: There is some good stuff here.  However, for now I'm not interested in testing JavaScript code.   I just want to run regular Java JUnit tests in a browser.