# Compilation type step for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jslint

I guess I am used to compiled static languages.

Is there a way to do the following with JavaScript.  JavaScript that mostly uses jQuery

1. Validate JavaScript script (also HTML document may be available), maybe use jslint
2. Run unit tests
3. Compress a set of JavaScript files into one large JavaScript file (maybe obfuscated)

Do you have an approach for compiling all of those steps into one command?   Like an ant script or maven script?

Comment: See the [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), a true optimizing compiler for JavaScript.

Comment: Create a make file. Run jslint, unit tests and uglify through your makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool)
2. [Google Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript.html) for minimizing javascript.
3. [Javascript obfuscation approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)