# Current State of Crossplatform JavaScript Unit and Systems Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, node.js

For JavaScript projects, what asynchronous system and unit test framework would be most conducive to use in both node.js and web browsers.

Ideally, the testing system would be able to execute some tests specifically for node.js and some in web browsers, while also having general tests which run in all environments.

Also, does anyone make automatable browser tests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a better JavaScript unit test tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of unittest frameworks for JavaScript:

- [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki)

  - BDD style
  - for both node and browser testing
  - can run via maven, so you can used with CI (Jenkins)
- [BusterJS](http://busterjs.org/)

  - its in beta state
  - BDD style
  - for both node and browser testing
  - Generates JUnit/Ant compatible XML output for use in continuous integration servers (Jenkins)
- [JSTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/)

  - Plugins for eclipse and IntelliJ/Webstorm
  - runs in the browser , result saved on the server
  - calc code coverage