# Code coverage for nightwatch.js using Istanbul

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul, nightwatch.js

Has anyone got code coverage to work for nightwatch.js with Istanbul. Any helpful links to the configuration will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nightwatch.js is a wrapper on Selenium. I believe what you attempting is not going to work with nightwatch.

See also
[Selenium: Is there any JS (JavaScript) code coverage tool which we can integrate with Selenium Server/RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495625/selenium-is-there-any-js-javascript-code-coverage-tool-which-we-can-integrate) where one user recommended [JsTestDriver](https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) instead.