# How can I automate the profiling of my page's JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testing, profiling, benchmarking

I have a web page with lots of JavaScript.  I am supposed to optimize the performance of the page.

Ideally, I would like to set up an automated test which would hover around the page and click on a couple of things.  Upon completing the test I'd like a profile of the JavaScript execution on the page.  This way I can make changes and see if the page will run faster or not.

If I cannot meet this ideal goal, what is the best I can do in terms of automating and standardizing tests of performance for my webpage?

Comment: "a test which would hover around the page" - What does this mean?

Comment: Have you tried the profiling tools in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Hover the mouse around the page is what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I want to use something like the profiling tools in Chrome and Firefox.  But I would like to have the test I perform be standardized and automated.

Answer (score 1):

That's hard and someday I will make it part of my development routine. The only proven solution is **continuous development** practice:

Use automated JS tests together with build server

Good frameworks list for js testing you may find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool)

Your build server have to has support for client javascript execution, as soon as I know there is [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/index.html) script which has many integration with different build servers, for example with one of the well known [Jenkins](http://www.readmore.ch/post/18940470535).

To be complete, you may use tools like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) instead of build server, but personally do not feel it is right way, though it may works good as well.

Comment: Will any of these let me do benchmarking to see how my page responds to various mouse movements on the page?

Comment: yes, I guess with bit on patience you may write appropriate tests, note that movements itself are nonsense, what's matter is hovering/clicking, and probably scrollings. all that you may emulate with javascript.