# How to run Jasmine tests on Node.js from command line

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

How do I run Jasmine tests on Node.js from command line? I have installed jasmine-node via npm and written some tests. I want to run tests inside the `spec` directory and get results in the terminal, is this possible?

Comment: Try this as well https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-node

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EDIT

It seems this is no longer the current best answer as the package is unmaintained. Please see the answer below

---

You can do this

from your test directory

```
sudo npm install jasmine-node
```

This installs jasmine into ../node_modules/jasmine-node

then

```
../node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node --verbose --junitreport --noColor spec
```

which from my [demo](https://github.com/JeremyMarshall/jasmine-node) does this

```
Player - 5 ms
    should be able to play a Song - 2 ms

    when song has been paused - 1 ms
        should indicate that the song is currently paused - 0 ms
        should be possible to resume - 0 ms
    tells the current song if the user has made it a favorite - 1 ms

    #resume - 0 ms
        should throw an exception if song is already playing - 0 ms

Player - 5 ms
    should be able to play a Song - 2 ms

    when song has been paused - 1 ms
        should indicate that the song is currently paused - 0 ms
        should be possible to resume - 0 ms
    tells the current song if the user has made it a favorite - 1 ms

    #resume - 0 ms
        should throw an exception if song is already playing - 0 ms

Finished in 0.01 seconds
5 tests, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

Comment: To those arriving via google: `jasmine-node` has had no new commits since 2014, only runs jasmine 1.3, and appears to have been abandoned. The official `jasmine` CLI in user64141's answer below is more up to date.

Comment: Avoid installing NPM packages with `sudo`. Only when really necessary, happens rarely.

Answer (score 95):

This should get you going quickly:

1. install Node.js (obviously).
2. Next install Jasmine. Open a command prompt and run:

   `npm install -g jasmine`
3. Next, cd to any directory and set up an example 'project':

   `jasmine init`
   `jasmine examples`
4. Now run your unit tests:

   `jasmine`

If your jasmine.json file is somewhere else besides spec/support/jasmine.json, simply run:

`jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=relative/path/to/your/jasmine.json`

For more info see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine
- http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/node.html

Comment: This info should definitely be more prominently included on the jasmine homepage. At the moment you only find out if you go to the github project.

Comment: Doing exactly this on a blank "npm init" project still yields no results for me.

Comment: This produces no output whatsoever.

Comment: I think that last link wants to point here now: https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to run the command in your project root:

`$ npx humile`

It founds all your specs which name ends with `.spec.js`.

If you think humile is fine for your project, just install it as dev dependency. It speeds up the command.

`$ npm install -D humile`

Answer (score -9):

Try Karma (formerly Testacular), it is a testing library agnostic test runner done by Angular.js team

http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html

Jasmine support is well baked.

http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/how-it-works.html

Comment: Karma doesn't run the tests in Node. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660670/how-to-test-nodejs-backend-code-with-karma-testacular.