# Timeout when attempting to connect to mongo from jest unit tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I want to write some unit tests with jest and mongoose to validate data interaction with mongo.

I don't want to mock mongoose here because I specifically want to validate the way that mongo documents are created/modified/handled.

`package.json` is configured to leave node modules unmocked:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

In my actual test, I have set up a `beforeAll()` hook to take care of connecting to mongo:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

describe('MyTest', () => {

  beforeAll((done) => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

    let db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', (err) => {
      done.fail(err);
    });

    db.once('open', () => {
      done();
    });
  });

  it('has some property', () => {
    // should pass but actually never gets run
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Here's the output:

```
/usr/local/bin/node node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --verbose
Using Jest CLI v0.10.0, jasmine2
 FAIL  src/lib/controllers/my-controller/__tests__/my-test.js (5.403s)
MyTest
  ✕ it has some property

MyTest › it has some property
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total in 1 test suite, run time 5.903s)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The test times out every time because `done()` is never called in the `beforeAll()` hook - no errors thrown nor anything printed to console.  I can place breakpoints in the `beforeAll()` hook to validate the code is being run.  It appears that mongoose is hanging whilst attempting to open a connection to Mongo, and then the jest tests are timing out.

When I'm running similar code outside of the jest environment, it connects as expected (nigh on instantly).  Suspecting that it could be causing problems, I've experimented with disabling jest's automock feature completely, but the behaviour remains unchanged.

I imagine I've missed something incredibly obvious... any ideas what could be going on?

- jest-cli v. 0.10.0
- mongoose v. 4.4.11

*Updates:*

- Tried replacing ES6 arrow function syntax with plain `function(done) {}`.  No difference.
- Tried making the test async by passing `done` parameter, and calling it on test completion.  No difference.
- Tried calling `mongoose.connect()` after the declaration of `error` and `connected` event handlers
- Tried commenting out all mongoose-related code to check that the `beforeAll()` hook is working correctly - it is.

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but did you try using function(done) instead of the ES6 arrow syntax? There are some subtle differences.

Comment: can you try below?
`it('has some property', (done) => {
    // should pass but actually never gets run
    expect(1).toBe(1);
    done();
  });`

Comment: Thanks - tried both suggestions to no avail, will add to my description.

Comment: Try to move `mongoose.connect` below the `db.once('open')`, if it doesn't help, replace `db.once('open')` to `db.on('connected')`.

Comment: @AlexanderMac - tried and also makes no difference.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that your test env is configured properly? Try to run  test without mongoose call, comment all the code in `beforeAll` and try to call `done()`.

Comment: What version of node.js are you using?

Comment: Also, what's the value of `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` ?

Comment: try passing `done` as the callback: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', done);`

Answer (score 2):

**Jest-jasmine is different from [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)**.
The syntax you used actually belongs to Jasmine 2.0+, not Jest-jasmine.  So if you want to continue to use jest, you have to look into jest docs to find the answer.
Even more, "beforeAll" is not a standard jest injected variables, see [jest api](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#globally-injected-variables).

I got your code run with Jasmine 2.3.4, it runs just fine. I tried Promise/pit in jest to finish this job but failed.

First, [install jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392370/how-to-run-jasmine-tests-on-node-js-from-command-line).

```
npm install -g jasmine
mkdir jasmine-test  
cd jasmine-test
jasmine init
jasmine examples
touch spec/mongodbspec.js
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
fenqideMacBook-Pro:jasmine-test fenqi$ ls -R
.:
spec/

./spec:
mongodbspec.js  support/

./spec/support:
jasmine.json
```

Then, edit spec/mongodbspec.js, I just add one line " 'use strict'; " to your code.

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

describe('MyTest', () => {

  beforeAll((done) => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

    let db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', (err) => {
      done.fail(err);
    });

    db.once('open', () => {
      done();
    });
  });

  it('has some property', () => {
    // should pass but actually never gets run
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Last, run 'jasmine' :

```
fenqideMacBook-Pro:jasmine-test fenqi$ jasmine
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.023 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it - it does help to know that my code isn't plainly broken!  Forgive me but you're answering a different question here :).  I'm aware that Jest uses a different flavour of Jasmine and those hooks are technically undocumented (but they do work).  I want to take advantage of Jest's built-in automock, and coverage etc..

Comment: Sorry that didn't solve your problem. Maybe you can hack Jest to support that syntax, but as i tried, it maybe complicate.