# Running fs-extra module functions with jasmine doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

When running the tests just using **jasmine** `"node_modules/.bin/jasmine" "spec\test_spec.js"`the `fs.remove` is not called - nothing happens (no error, nothing).

When running tests using **jasmine-node** `"node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node" "spec\test_spec.js"` the fs function is correctly called.

But jasmine-node is not [maintained anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392370/how-to-run-jasmine-tests-on-node-js-from-command-line) and it should be possible to do everything with just jasmine. Any ideas? Should we run these tests differently?

In describe block we have afterEach which works correctly.

```
afterEach(function () {
    sfnc.deleteProjectFolders(projectName);
});
```

The fs.remove is not called / nothing happens

```
...
var fs = require('fs-extra');
...
exports.deleteProjectFolders = function (listOfFolders, pathToRootFolder) {
    ....
    console.log("This is called correctly");
    // This is not called - nothing happens 
    fs.remove(fl, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            exports.debugLog("Failed to delete folder {},\n Error: {} ".format(
                fl, err), true)
        }else{
            exports.debugLog("Folder {} deleted.".format(fl));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fs.remove()` is async call. The test has to wait for it to finish. We need to add [callback](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) to the afterEach function.

Solution with simple callback:

```
afterEach(function (done) {
    sfnc.deleteProjectFolders(projectName, done);
});
```

And in the function:

```
...
var fs = require('fs-extra');
...
exports.deleteProjectFolders = function (listOfFolders, callback) {
    ....
    fs.remove(fl, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            exports.debugLog("Failed to delete folder {},\n Error: {} ".format(fl, err), true)
        }else{
            exports.debugLog("Folder {} deleted.".format(fl));
        }
        callback()
    });
}
```

Or it could be written as promise.