# Karma tests, PhantomJS error: Could not find module 'events'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm writing a Node.js project using TypeScript. The compilation is done using `tsc`, I am not using any task runner like Gulp or Grunt. I'll try to be as concise as possible, however if any further details are needed I'll gladly provide them.

I have the following class:

```
// Foo.ts
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
export class Foo extends EventEmitter {
  //...
}
```

When I try to test it using Jasmine with Karma and PhantomJS, I get the following error: `Error: Could not find module 'events' from '(...)/foo.js'`. For me it seems that PhantomJS doesn't know where to take `events` module from.

My `karma.conf.js` looks as follows:

```
var createCoverageReport = false;

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript', 'es6-shim'],
    files: [
      'src/**/*.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.ts': ['karma-typescript']
    },
    reporters: ['spec'].concat(createCoverageReport ? ['karma-typescript'] : []),
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

How can I let PhantomJS know, that the `events` module comes from Node.js inner modules?

Comment: any update on this? same problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to [an answer to a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660909/6696238) it's not possible to do so on purpose.

Karma is a test runner for testing frontend code **only**. That's how it was designed. Therefore, you cannot require any node internal library without using weird workarounds.

If you'd like to test the backend code, go ahead and use e.g. [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) instead of Karma and Jasmine. Moving to this libraries wasn't very painful and I can totally recommend doing so.

Moreover, [this article](https://templecoding.com/blog/2016/05/05/unit-testing-with-typescript-and-mocha/) provides good introduction on how to use Mocha with TypeScript so I suggest reading it first.