# Should I be using Protractor or Karma for my end-to-end testing?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Should I be using Protractor or Karma for my end-to-end testing?

Angular-seed is using Protractor/Selenium WebDriver for E2E but the angular-phonecat tutorial uses karma.

I read that I should use Karma for unit tests and Protractor for E2E, which seems fine but I thought I would ask on here to get other dev's opinions.

Comment: Better fit for [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Though if you do post this question there you will have to elaborate what your requirements are. [Related meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-alright-to-ask-for-programming-tools)

Comment: Karma and Protractor are both used and recommended by the Angular team, but given the state of documentation (ie: there's tons of it and it's difficult to know what's up to date) it's difficult to know which to use and for which purpose.  This is a good question and glpretre's answer was exactly what I was looking for, too.

Comment: I don't think the question was too broad (Protractor vs Karma). It's frameworks we are talking about here, not just some software, so the question is in it's right place.

Comment: See my answer here for more detailed discussion of use cases, advantages and limitations of Karma and Protractor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29619467/1614973

Comment: My understanding is that Protractor does not allow to test only a part of
your app without the presence of the rest (e.g. mocking):
the test code isn't even running in the same JS interpreter as the
application. No filesystem monitoring for source code modifications
and automatic re-triggering of the affected tests.
Karma provides these. It sends test code + app code in <script>s to the
browser so they run in the same interpreter, mocking possible, but is not
designed for end-to-end testing with native events
as if a real user were acting.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The AngularJS team recommends using Protractor as it's going to replace angular scenario runner:

> Angular Scenario Runner is in maintenance mode - If you're starting a new Angular project, consider using [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor).

quoted from [AngularJs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing).

The tutorial angular-phonecat was developed a long time ago (in 2011 mainly) and has not yet been updated to use some Angular new features like Protractor.

**EDIT**

In the [Protractor Docs - FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md):

> ### Why both Karma and Protractor? When do I use which?
>
> Karma is a great tool for unit testing, and Protractor is intended for
> end to end or integration testing. This means that small tests for the
> logic of your individual controllers, directives, and services should
> be run using Karma. Big tests in which you have a running instance of
> your entire application should be run using Protractor. Protractor is
> intended to run tests from a user's point of view - if your test could
> be written down as instructions for a human interacting with your
> application, it should be an end to end test written with Protractor.
>
> Here's a [great blog post](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/09/advanced-testing-and-debugging-in-angularjs.html) with more info.

Comment: From Karma FAQ - http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/intro/faq.html - Can I use Karma to do end to end testing ?
Karma has primarily been designed for low level (unit) testing. If it's an AngularJS app, you can use Karma with karma-ng-scenario plugin, however we recommend Protractor for high level testing.

Comment: If I want unit testing as well as e2e testing then i have to configure karma environment for unit testing and protractor for ui testing or e2e testing ?

Comment: @SunilGarg Yes you have to, maybe our starter app structure could help you : https://github.com/glepretre/angular-requirejs-ready (ignore requireJS specifics if you don't use it)