# how to test angularjs app using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

I am currently using Karma and Jasmine for doing the unit test my first angular App.
Now I want to test my App's HTML elements but I couldn't find any way to do that in karma test runner. I read that this is only possible with protractor. I have no idea of writing and running test in protractor, can anyone help me out? 
OR 
Suggest if there is a way to test HTML in karma?
Because I am using Karma for controller testing, is it possible to test HTML as well in Karma then it'll be super helpful.
For protractor, can I test my controller as well in protractor??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are two very different major *types of tests/categories* that are usually written for AngularJS applications: unit tests and end-to-end tests.

For unit testing of your directives, controllers, services - use `karma`.

For end-to-end testing - use `protractor`.

---

Related quote from the [Protractor's FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#whats-the-difference-between-karma-and-protractor-when-do-i-use-which):

> Karma is a great tool for unit testing, and Protractor is intended for
>   end to end or integration testing. This means that **small tests for the
>   logic of your individual controllers, directives, and services should
>   be run using Karma**. **Big tests in which you have a running instance of
>   your entire application should be run using Protractor.** Protractor is
>   intended to run tests from a user's point of view - if your test could
>   be written down as instructions for a human interacting with your
>   application, it should be an end to end test written with Protractor.

See also:

- [Should I be using Protractor or Karma for my end-to-end testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732379/should-i-be-using-protractor-or-karma-for-my-end-to-end-testing)
- [Can Protractor and Karma be used together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070522/can-protractor-and-karma-be-used-together)
- [Advanced Testing and Debugging in AngularJS](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/09/advanced-testing-and-debugging-in-angularjs.html)

Comment: it seems that HTML testing is not possible in unit testing?

Comment: @Hassan it depends on what do you mean by "HTML testing". You can [test directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-directives). You can test your complete application from the user's perspective in a browser with the help of protractor.

Comment: here is HTML  <th id="test" colspan="2">First Angular JS App</th> and now i am trying to test this in karma  it('should show the number of items in list',function() {
       
        expect($('#test').text()).toBe('First Angular JS App');
    });

Comment: @Hassan well, this sounds like a UI test and a job for protractor.

Comment: @alecexe thanks for your time now what can i do am really confused by angular testing now how can i kickstart very shortly with protractor to test this i mentioned above?