# AngularJS testing? Unit Testing and E2E testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, integration-testing, karma-runner, protractor

I have been reading that karma is used for angular unit testing and protractor is for end-to-end testing. If we want to have both unit and E2E testing in my angular application, then how do should it look like? How do I incorporate both? In order to have both of these tests included in our suite, should we use both karma (for unit testing) and protractor (for E2E testing) for the same application? Is that a healthy way to go about it?
P.S: Post is open to all the approaches to achieve this.

Comment: See this existing question: [Can Protractor and Karma be used together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070522/can-protractor-and-karma-be-used-together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to run unit tests on Protractor but it's better to separate unit and e2e test runners.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why-both-karma-and-protractor-when-do-i-use-which