# Angular js - Is using Karma and Protractor both in a project an overkill?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, protractor

While, a google search gives the purpose for Karma and Protractor, I am keen to know as to what are the best practices when it comes to writing automated tests. Is it a recommended practice to write both Karma and Protractor tests? Is this an overkill on the project. How can one find the optimal balance?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070522/can-protractor-and-karma-be-used-together?rq=1

Comment: Karma is primarily for unit testing, as protractor is for e2e.

Comment: I know what each does. The purpose is clear. Should we use both for all projects?

Comment: @Aneesh: if you want to be serious about testing, then yes.

Comment: My personal approach is to skip e2e (protractor) for small project / simple things, but do unit tests (karma) always!

Comment: delivering a buggy product is always bad and since new untested ui elements can have bugs too, why not testing them?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an overkill!

Only Protractor runs end-to-end (e2e) tests, i.e. your complete application, so this is the only reliable way to test the end result.

However, errors due to individual pieces of your code are hard to track with e2e tests. Also Protractor is slow and not suitable for running in background upon every source file edit, as Karma can do.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29619467/1614973) for more detailed discussion of use cases, advantages and limitations of Karma and Protractor.