# What should i use for AngularJS E2E tests? Protractor or Angular Scenario Runner or Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, protractor

On [Protractor github](https://github.com/angular/protractor) it says "Protractor is an end to end test framework for AngularJS",

from what i read over the net AngularJS Scenario Runner is deprecated, and shouldn't be used

anymore, and [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html), well to tell the truth i use it to run jasmine tests but i'm not even

sure it's can be used to run E2E.

So what should i use? is Protractor is the answer, should I use it?

Is AngularJS Scenario Runner really deprecated?

Comment: I believe protractor is the go to e2e test framework for Angular. Julie on the NG team is actively working on it and mostly everyone I know doing e2e with NG is using it. So +1 for protractor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/). 
Advantages:

- Autowaits for xhr request, elements, animations etc. You don't need to use `browser.wait`, `browser.isElementPresent(elm)`, `elm.isPresent()`, `elm.isElementPresent()`
- Simple installation
- Supports the most popular browsers
- Mobile testing

I tried `testcafe` for new project and I like it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use Protractor assuming you are running Angular 1.2. All the current E2E tests are run in it AFAIK.

Its your choice of course but Protractor seems to be the way to go.

Some slides - http://goo.gl/bl9Lw

Protractor Github - https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Answer (score 0):

**Karma** is not suitable for E2E because it does not test your complete application, only individual pieces of your code.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29619467/1614973) for more detailed discussion of use cases, advantages and limitations of Karma and Protractor.