# Which URL to use when working with $httpBackend expectGET

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, httpbackend

When expecting a call to the API should I include the entire URL including all the parameters, or do I just need a partial match?

Should I be listening for a call to the exact URL :

`http://address.of.api/stuff/123?include=thing,anotherthing.name;`

Or do I just need this :

`/stuff/123`

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) is part of Angular's Mock environment designed to replace real backend by fake one, or rather by **imitating** how Angular's `$http` works without real backend.

As much as I love Angular, I find `$httpBackend` *over-engineered* and unnecessarily complicated for what it does:

- It is *not recommended* way to throw complicated code inside your tests. The more you do it, the more chance is that you create errors in that **testing code** instead of what you are actually supposed to test.
- It promotes the bad practice of placing `$http` (or other low-level services in your abstraction hierarchy) freely around your code, as you can later use that `$httpBackend` to mock it away.

Instead it works cleaner to isolate any reference to low level methods into dedicated methods of your own, whose single responsibility is to make http requests. These dedicated methods should be able to work with real backend, not a fake one!

[More details here on Angular testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29619467/1614973)