# Karma - Use PhantomJS instead of Chrome

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up automated testing with Karma. Although I ran into a problem.

npm start or npm install give me this error:

```
> concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

[0] /c: /c: is a directory
[1] /c: /c: is a directory
[0] npm run tsc:w exited with code 126
[1] npm run lite exited with code 126

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ivar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Before they gave me:

```
> karma start karma.conf.js

29 09 2016 16:49:27.659:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/Ivar/documents/school/stage/workspace/webapplicatie/systemjs.config.extras.js" does not match any file.
29 09 2016 16:49:27.679:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/Ivar/documents/school/stage/workspace/webapplicatie/app/**/*.css" does not match any file.
29 09 2016 16:49:27.691:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/Ivar/documents/school/stage/workspace/webapplicatie/test/**/*.ts" does not match any file.
29 09 2016 16:49:27.692:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/Ivar/documents/school/stage/workspace/webapplicatie/test/**/*.js.map" does not match any file.
29 09 2016 16:49:28.158:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
29 09 2016 16:49:28.159:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
29 09 2016 16:49:28.166:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
29 09 2016 16:49:29.956:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#GGY-X69uV6wlYJOnAAAA with id 60252055
29 09 2016 16:49:30.387:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'System.config')
  at karma-test-shim.js:30

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'System.config')
  at karma-test-shim.js:30

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

while in node_modules/systemjs/dist the sytem-polyfills.js does exist.

Now my karma config code:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  var testBase    = 'test/';       // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrcBase = 'test/';       // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'), // click "Debug" in browser to see it
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter') // crashing w/ strange socket error
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false},
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    // disabled HtmlReporter; suddenly crashing w/ strange socket error
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],//'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Karma shim

```
// #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/app/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  baseURL: '/base',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
  .then(importSystemJsExtras)
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
function importSystemJsExtras(){
  return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
  .catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(
      'Warning: System.import could not load the optional "systemjs.config.extras.js". Did you omit it by accident? Continuing without it.'
    );
    console.log(reason);
  });
}

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
    console.log("init testing");
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {

        console.log("module: "+moduleName);
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

last but not least 
package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",

    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server":"~2.2.2",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.13",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Sorry for the amount of code but I can't seem to find the problem myself.

**Edit: it works local, on server I get this error:**

```
 angular-quickstart@1.0.0 test-once /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:17    > tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:17    
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:37    [33m03 10 2016 09:03:37.209:WARN [watcher]: [39mPattern "/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/systemjs.config.extras.js" does not match any file.
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:37    [33m03 10 2016 09:03:37.229:WARN [watcher]: [39mPattern "/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/app/**/*.css" does not match any file.
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:37    [33m03 10 2016 09:03:37.241:WARN [watcher]: [39mPattern "/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/test/**/*.ts" does not match any file.
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:37    [33m03 10 2016 09:03:37.242:WARN [watcher]: [39mPattern "/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/test/**/*.js.map" does not match any file.
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:40    [32m03 10 2016 09:03:40.938:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:40    [32m03 10 2016 09:03:40.939:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:40    [32m03 10 2016 09:03:40.973:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.068:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: [39m/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.069:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: [39m/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.081:ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start PhantomJS
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41        
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.086:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: [39m/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [32m03 10 2016 09:03:41.090:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.103:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: [39m/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.104:ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start PhantomJS
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41        
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [32m03 10 2016 09:03:41.106:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start PhantomJS again (2/2).
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.112:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: [39m/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.112:ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start PhantomJS
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41        
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.113:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: [39m/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MA-JOB1/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs)
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    
build   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    [31m03 10 2016 09:03:41.114:ERROR [launcher]: [39mPhantomJS failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! Linux 2.6.18-92.1.22.el5
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! argv "/opt/node-v0.12.7-linux-x86/bin/node" "/opt/node-v0.12.7-linux-x86/bin/npm" "run" "test-once"
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! node v0.12.7
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 test-once: `tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run`
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! Exit status 1
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! 
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 test-once script 'tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run'.
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR!     tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
error   03-Oct-2016 09:03:41    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Karma error stems from the 404 above it. Karma isn't serving the `system-polyfills.js` file.  You need to add it or more likely `system-polyfills.src.js`to the files section above `system.src.js`.  If you haven't created `systemjs.config.extras.js` as well you'll get another less critical error after that.  If you don't have one just create an empty file with that name.

If `npm start` and `npm test` still fail after that please update your question with the output from `npm install` and I'll update this answer.

Comment: updated the answer, it does work on my local machine but when I deploy it to my server (c.i.) I get the error shown in the answer.

Comment: PhantomJS is not running on your server because you're missing libraries it needs.  `/lib/libz.so.1`, `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6`, and `/usr/lib/libc.so.6`.  You'll need to install them and probably others once those are in.  A quick google search of the error makes me think phantomjs may not be supported on your distro/version. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13940 . You glibc version seems too old or otherwise incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be sourced from the incompatible systems of Karma and Protractor which aren't recommended to be used together:

> https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/9#issuecomment-19927049
>
> Protractor and Karma should not be used together; instead they provide separate systems for running tests. Protractor and Karma cover different aspects of testing - Karma is intended mostly for unit tests, while Protractor should be used for end to end testing.
>
> Protractor is built on top of WebDriverJS, which uses a Selenium/WebDriver server to provision browsers and drive test execution. Examples of pure WebDriverJS can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs
>
> https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/9#issuecomment-19931154
>
> Georgios - I think it makes sense to keep Protractor and Karma separate - for end to end tests, you want the native event driving and flexibility of webdriver, while for unit tests you want fast execution and autowatching of files.

Original answer was found here:
[Can Protractor and Karma be used together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070522/can-protractor-and-karma-be-used-together)