# Javascript test framework for ExtJS and Spring 3.0 MVC

Tags: javascript, spring, unit-testing, model-view-controller, extjs

I am working on an Enterprise product which is based on Spring MVC as back end and Ext JS as front end.

We are planning to provide extensions/customizations on this application in a supported manner.

For Java (Spring MVC) based testing, we identified the required tools for testing.

We are relatively new to Ext JS and in fact javascript frameworks.

What should be the approach for complete test suite for the UI?  We need Unit Testing and BDD for the UI (Ext JS) code we are writing.

I followed this thread and it says about different products but I dont find a solution for end-to-end set up of test project.
[JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool)

Any body can provide any inputs on this?

Answer (score 2):

Try Jasmine. It's BDD and fits perfectly to test the UI.
[Here's](http://compiledammit.com/2012/09/06/using-jasmine-to-test-an-extjs-application/) an article on how to use it with Ext JS