# Javascript testing tool

Tags: javascript

Any idea of how I can test a graph that is written in javascript e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967 Is there any automation tool? or I should write unit test individually for each function? I am new to javascript and I need to know if there is any framework or tool is needed for testing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend testing each function using something like [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) to start with. This will ensure the internal behaviour is correct. You could also try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to run the JavaScript and produce an image of the chart to ensure it looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

The [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool) gives you a rundown on pretty much all of the available options for unit testing in JavaScript.

To summarise that, [Buster.js](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/) is a very popular option.

Answer (score 0):

There was a talk at [NDCOslo](http://www.ndcoslo.com/): Which James Shore talks about testdriven JavaScript and he talks about: DOM testing, mouse events, touch events, SVG, and more...

Its a "masters class" but i think it explains the things you are asking about:

[James Shore: Test-Driven JavaScript Master Class](http://vimeo.com/68383288)

There are also more JavaScript talks there if you like watching videos to learn more:
[Other JavaScript videos from NDCOslo](http://vimeo.com/ndcoslo/videos/page:1/search%3ajavascript/sort%3adate/format%3adetail)