# What is JavaScript unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

What is JavaScript unit testing? I am a web developer; how can I take advantage of this technique?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/unit-testing/info

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=unit+testing

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing in JavaScript is the same concept as other languages. Since JavaScript takes place in modifying the HTML, the GUI modifications (adding/modifying elements etc') should be tested as well as the logic behind.

**Reviews of popular JavaScript unit testing frameworks/tools:**

- *[JavaScript Unit Testing Tools](http://abundantcode.com/javascript-unit-testing-tools/)*
- *[JavaScript Unit Test Tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd)*

**Here is a list of popular JavaScript unit testing frameworks:**

- [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/)
- [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)
- [Tutti](http://tuttijs.com)
- [TestSwarm](http://swarm.jquery.org/)
- [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/)
- [jsUnity](http://jsunity.com)
- [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/)

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you need to read up on unit testing in general and then on the unique challenges posed by JavaScript to good unit testing.

[Aviran made a great suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201783/what-is-javascript-unit-testing/19201825#19201825) with QUnit, but I think [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) is better suited for new developers because of its readability and [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)-ness.

Either way, you will be able to make the right choice for you and your applications as you try these tools and get more experience...and feel the pain of not having those unit tests.