# Can anyone suggest me javascript testing framework which can be run from command line and result are in console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

Can anyone suggest me javascript testing framework which can be run from command line and result are in console ?
I am new to node.ja and javascript, I tried with jasmine but it is hard to run from commadn line.

Comment: http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always been a fan of jasmine but if you are looking for something with command line you could try **[BusterJs](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/)** or **[Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html)**!

EDIT:

Also see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd)**

Answer (score 1):

I am very happy with Karma + Mocha + Chai + Sinon

It sounds like a lot, but they are nice pieces that fit together