# Functional tests in Django reusable apps

Tags: django, testing, selenium, integration-testing

I'm writing a Django reusable app. It's not a usual app which can be used on its own. It requires other apps to be usable just like django.contrib.admin or django-dajaxice do.

My current project tree looks like this:

```
django-myapp/
    docs/
        some.rst
        docs.rst
        ...
    myapp/
        static/
            myapp/
                some_js_stuff.js
        templatetags/
            some_file.py
        __init__.py
        base.py
        manager.py
        ...
    unit_tests/
        __init__.py
        test_base.py
        test_manager.py
    functional_tests/
        __init__.py
        functional_tests.py
        urls.py
    README.rst
    LICENSE
    requirements.txt
    requirements-test.txt
    setup.py
    ...
```

Unit tests are easy - I'm just testing my code so I don't need complete Django environment to run them. Simple `./setup.py test` works  perfectly.

Functional testing is the tricky part. I would like to use selenium so I need running dev server and this requires whole Django environment. I'm trying to use `django.test.LiveServerTestCase` but with no success (It looks like there were no urls defined, setting `ROOT_URLCONF` in `settings` and `urls` attribute in class didn't help).

Every piece of documentation I've found, every question on stackoverflow tells about testing Django apps inside Django project. And here is my question: what is the best (and working) way to run functional/integration tests of reusable app without setting up complete Django project?

Comment: I assume you have a local development version that works fine?  `LiveServerTestCase` essentially requires a working dev environment, but it will use a test database and do the standard setup/teardown for each test it runs.  It is hard to run functional tests on something that isn't functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Nathan says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096999/functional-tests-in-django-reusable-apps#comment33662289_22096999) its hard to test a unit in a whole stack, without the stack. So you have to have a settings file. Have a look at how the excellent [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) app does it:

It has a [Makefile](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/Makefile) with a `test_selenium` rule:

```
test_selenium:
    DJANGO_SELENIUM_TESTS=true DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=tests.settings \
        django-admin.py test tests
```

And in its [tests](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/tree/master/tests) module it has a bare bones [settings.py](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/tests/settings.py)  with the bare necessities:

- `INSTALLED_APPS` with the app under test
- `ROOT_URLCONF` wich points to the urls.py
- stuff like `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` that *you* may skip because you have none.

and a [test_integration.py](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/tests/test_integration.py)

```
@skipUnless('DJANGO_SELENIUM_TESTS' in os.environ, "selenium tests not requested")
class DebugToolbarLiveTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    ...
```

Study their setup. Start at the Makefile and dig down making sure you understand why everything is there.

I like that setup because integration/functional tests tend to be dogslow. Understandably, they test the whole stack with all its moving parts. Their Makefile gives an easy way to skip them. If I were to have a reusable app that uses Javascript, I'd have a look at [jasmine](/questions/tagged/jasmine) too. Or some [other tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/680713/383793) to unittest the javascript. Because running the slow integrationtests just to see if the js units work is a pain.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. This is exactly what I was looking for :)
I know that I need minimal initialization of Django stack but I didn't know how to do it correctly. I experimented with custom test runner or with setting up stack inside my functional test module but it didn't work.