# Automated testing using js framework

Tags: automated-tests

I need an automated testing framework that can browse between pages that can use javascript to write tests. Does anyone has any suggestions?
To be more clear I need something like selenium with the ability to navigate between pages so qunit is out of the question.

Comment: This is too broad for the SO format.  Do a bit of research and if you have specific questions you can ask them here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd)

Comment: I do not need unit testing and TDD, I need something like selenium but js based and simple to use like this: http://dalekjs.com/, but with the capability to navigate between pages.