# Is there any unit testing integration in nodeclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, unit-testing, nodeclipse

am I correct in thinking that nodeclipse does not yet provide unit test integration à la JUnit?
I was hoping to be able to run tests individually, by script, by folder... but can't seem to find a way to do that.

Eric

Answer (score 1):

[It is open issue #34 in the Noodeclipse project issue tracker](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/34), so no.

Comment: I don't like "their" word.  For me Nodeclipse started as research on existing tools, while anyone comes with some additions to Nodeclipse, the project grows.

Answer (score 0):

As Node.js is using JavaScript, so you should actually search for JUnit-like integration for JavaScript.

And there are [many unit testing framework for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd),
and I don't know any mature Eclipse integration.

[Quick search](https://www.wow.com/search?q=JUnit-like%20integration%20for%20JavaScript&s_pt=aolsem&s_it=opensearch) right now gives me

- https://github.com/wgroeneveld/jasmine-junit-runner

[image]

- [JavaScript tests with JUnit](https://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2013/01/27/javascript-tests-with-junit/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [benjiweber.co.uk](http://benjiweber.co.uk/testoutput1.png))</sub>

I remember there were some others, but they all required tedious set-up work.
I don't know which project worth including into Nodeclipse.

You can help Nodeclipse by researching and giving more options here
or directly to [#34](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/34)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but this does not run unit tests against Node.js.