# Configure Eclipse Node JS IDE (Enide) to run nodeunit

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeunit, enide

I am playing around with Enide, an Eclipse IDE for Node-JS development, and nodeunit, a JUnit-like testframework. How do I need to configure Enide, that I will be able to see a 'Run as XUnit-test'-entry in the Eclipse context menu?

Answer (score 0):

Currently not possible, see [Is there any unit testing integration in nodeclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211677/is-there-any-unit-testing-integration-in-nodeclipse)

I researched before, but not working on more. Welcome on GitHub to work on https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues