# How can I create integration test with intern?

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing

It is possible to create integration test with intern? Or also something like send inputs to a function that call's a ajax function and mock/stub the response of the ajax call?

And the second question is: is there a tool to simply run the test of javascript in an IDE? (like the junit testing) So you can see the result without a html page?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd) will guide you through Test Driven Development in JS

Comment: At the end of the answer I can read: Selenium is for integration testing, while the tools here are for unit testing. This means that I have to work with Selenium!