# How to test front end features with rspec?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, vue.js

I'm using vue.js in rails project, but only core library.
Now, most form in the project developed with vue.js. I use feature test in rspec to test the front end feature, such as fill from or form validations, but found it so hard.

These some pain point when I write test:

1. I need to add id for each html tag just for capabara to selector item. You know, with vue.js, we don't need any tag id or class for item selecting.
2. How can I unit test js feature? I just only use feature test, but when project growing, test writing become harder and harder.

Is there any easier way or best practice?

Comment: Do you mean BDD?

Comment: I'm now acting BDD with Rspec, and found some pain point in testing front end, expect to figure out some more effective practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind that Capybara support many different [**selectors**](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/selectors), which you can use to locate elements without having to always add a CSS class or id.

An even better alternative when creating your own components in Vue, is to always render a `data-qa` or `name` attribute on links and button elements (which is not necessarily the label, but can default to it), and then [configure Capybara to use that](https://github.com/ElMassimo/capybara_test_helpers/blob/master/spec/support/global_filters.rb#L6-L8) to find your elements.

```rb
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.test_id = 'data-qa'
end
```

```rb
click_link('cart.checkout')
```

For unit testing JS, you could try using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) or [Mocha-Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha). For example, assuming that you have a configuration that uses `vue-cli`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test:mocha": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jasmine. It's very popular and close to Rspec syntax. 
Anyway, There is plenty of tools to do that: [JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd)