# How to write Unit Test case for the Type Script code block

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I use to write Unit Test case in C# but for Typescript I do not know how to write it. Please help me someone. I tried to type here the code block but was unable to post this due to formatting issue so I just pasted it here as an image.

**Even if someone can describe the use case here for unit test would be of great help.**

[Code Block]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOtIK.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd)

Comment: It appears you are asking for tools to use for unit testing in typescript/javascript, which the above question has a lot of suggestions for.

Comment: Thanks Dakeyras... First of all I am not getting clarity on what use cases I have to create for testing the code block attached as an image... If you can provide the use cases for the same it would be of great help...